# CSS box-shadow & margin

Tags: layout, margin, css

I have added CSS `box-shadow` to `<img>` in a blog post. The imgs have `max-width:100%` set so that they fill the column when it is resized.

The shadow spills out into margins due to box-shadow rendering outside of border in the CSS box model. I want to give the images some extra margin so that the shadow sits inside of the column. However if I use `margin` this will make the imgs wider than the column.

Is there a nice way to make the shadow sit inside without affecting the width as above?
Thought of wrapping in another element but it's a shame to do that.

If I had used solid borders I could have used `box-sizing:border-box;` to achieve this but it doesn't have any bearing on `box-shadow`?

Comment: In the future you will be able to use `calc(...)`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-calc

Comment: Sweeet! There's some really nice stuff in the pipeline, like HTML 5 `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` values for getting true dimensions of img :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about max-width 98% or alightly lower and then the shadow should be just inside?

Comment: I like that idea but pixel precision would be perfect if it's possible!

Comment: I can't think of anything else. Wrapping it in another element would give you more control.

Comment: maybe a shadow with a percentage size?